# How to save log-in state in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to build an app for WP8 with a login page. I want to save the user login state so that the end-user will not have to retype his/her credentials, my app is a HTML page embedded in the webbrowser control.
Someone Can help me how save login state ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if the website you are trying to log in to is not yours then what you ask for cannot be done.

Now assuming that you are using a `WebBrowser` in your XAML code and that the website you log in to is yours lets say you have a login successfull method:

there you have to call this code:

`window.external.notify("LogInSuccess");`

Then your `WebBrowser` should be like this:

`<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="webBrowserControl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsScriptEnabled="True" ScriptNotify="JavaScriptNotify"/>`

And the method that gets called in .cs file should actually store a success value into isolated storage that will be checked every time you open the login page:

```
void JavaScriptNotify(Object sender, NotifyEventArgs notifyArgs)
{
    // Check if the value is correct:
    if (notifyArgs.Value.Equals("LogInSuccess"))
    {
        // Save State to Isolated Storage
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings.Add("loginStatus ", "success");
    }
}
```

Finally you should override the constructor method of your login page to the following:

public LoginPage()
{
    var loginStatus = settings["loginStatus "].ToString();
    if (loginStatus.Equals(success))
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/PageAfterLoginPage.xaml, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}

And for this to be complete override the `OnNavigatedTo` method of PageAfterLoginPage.xaml and add the following code:

`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();`

Last part will just remove the login page from the stack so that when the user clicks the back button wont be navigated to that screen again.